# Jump to function when key is pressed

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I made some hardware for my Raspberry Pi's GPIO that I'd like to test. I found some neat python code that makes 8 buttons for the 8 outputs, and lets you toggle their state. I have almost no knowledge of python, but I'd like to be able to toggle the 8 outputs via keyboard (ex. numbers 1-8). I don't know how to ask for a keyboard input without pausing the flow of the program then continuing after response.

How can I make the numbers 1-8 "interrupt" my program and jump to 1 of the 8 corresponding functions?

My code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode( GPIO.BCM )
GPIO.setup( 4, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(22, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(25, GPIO.OUT)

class App:
    io4=0
    io17=0
    io18=0
    io21=0
    io22=0
    io23=0
    io24=0
    io25=0

    def __init__(self, master):

        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        self.p1 = Button(frame, text="GPIO 25",fg="green", command=self.gpio25)
        self.p1.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.p1.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.p2 = Button(frame, text="GPIO 24",fg="red", command=self.gpio24)
        self.p2.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.p2.grid(row=0,column=1)

        self.p3 = Button(frame, text="GPIO 23",fg="red", command=self.gpio23)
        self.p3.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.p3.grid(row=0,column=2)

        self.p4 = Button(frame, text="GPIO 22",fg="red", command=self.gpio22)
        self.p4.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.p4.grid(row=0,column=3)

        self.p5 = Button(frame, text="GPIO 21",fg="red", command=self.gpio21)
        self.p5.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.p5.grid(row=0,column=4)

        self.p6 = Button(frame, text="GPIO 18",fg="red", command=self.gpio18)
        self.p6.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.p6.grid(row=0,column=5)

        self.p7 = Button(frame, text="GPIO 17",fg="red", command=self.gpio17)
        self.p7.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.p7.grid(row=0,column=6)


        self.p8 = Button(frame, text="GPIO 4", fg="red",command=self.gpio4)
        self.p8.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.p8.grid(row=0,column=7)

    def gpio4(self):
        if self.io4==0:
          GPIO.output(4, GPIO.HIGH)
          self.io4=1
        else:
          GPIO.output(4, GPIO.LOW)
          self.io4=0
        return

    def gpio17(self):
        if self.io17==0:
          GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
          self.io17=1
        else:
          GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)
          self.io17=0
        return

    def gpio18(self):
        if self.io18==0:
          GPIO.output(18, GPIO.HIGH)
          self.io18=1
        else:
          GPIO.output(18, GPIO.LOW)
          self.io18=0
        return

    def gpio21(self):
        if self.io21==0:
          GPIO.output(21, GPIO.HIGH)
          self.io21=1
        else:
          GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW)
          self.io21=0
        return

    def gpio22(self):
        if self.io22==0:
          GPIO.output(22, GPIO.HIGH)
          self.io22=1
        else:
          GPIO.output(22, GPIO.LOW)
          self.io22=0
        return

    def gpio23(self):
        if self.io23==0:
          GPIO.output(23, GPIO.HIGH)
          self.io23=1
        else:
          GPIO.output(23, GPIO.LOW)
          self.io23=0
        return

    def gpio24(self):
        if self.io24==0:
          GPIO.output(24, GPIO.HIGH)
          self.io24=1
        else:
          GPIO.output(24, GPIO.LOW)
          self.io24=0
        return

    def gpio25(self):
        if self.io25==0:
          GPIO.output(25, GPIO.HIGH)
          self.io25=1
        else:
          GPIO.output(25, GPIO.LOW)
          self.io25=0
        return

    def reserved(self):
        return

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `master.bind(...)` commands to the `__init__` method:

```
def __init__(self, master):

    frame = Frame(master)
    frame.pack()
    master.bind('1', self.gpio25)
    master.bind('2', self.gpio24)
    master.bind('3', self.gpio23)
    ...
```

---

`master.bind('1', self.gpio25)` binds the keypress `1` event to the method call `self.gpio25(event)`.
You will need 7 more `master.bind` calls -- one for each key.

Next, modify the definition of the callback functions. You will need to add a second argument, `event`, to each of them. Change, for example,

```
def gpio25(self):
```

to

```
def gpio25(self, event = None):
```

---

**Explanation:**

When you use the `bind` method, you are binding an `Event` to a callback function (e.g. `self.gpio25`). Pressing a key is a KeyPress Event. Information about the event is sent to the callback in an Event object. Thus the callback function must take one argument. 
See [Tkinter events and bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) for more information.

`Buttons` work differently. Their callback functions are called with zero arguments.

Since we are using the same callback function, `self.gpio25`, as both a Keypress event callback and as a Button callback, it must be a function that can take zero or one argument.

In Python, the way to do that is to define `gpio25` with a call signature like:

```
def gpio25(self, event = None):
```

`self` is an instance of the class `App`. `self.gpio25` is a bound method with `self` bound as its first argument. So calling `self.gpio25()` will call the `gpio25` function with `self` as the first argument (and the local variable `event` will be assigned the value `None`). Calling `self.gpio25(foo)` will call `gpio25` with `self` as the first argument, and `foo` as the second argument (and the local variable `event` will be assigned the value `foo`).

In your case, the value assigned to `event` does not really matter, since `event` is not used in the body of `gpio25`. We just needed to set up `self.gpio25` to be ready to accept zero or one argument.

Comment: Awesome, i'll try it in a bit and see who it goes :)

Comment: Can you explain the "event = none" part?